# Как правильно убрать верхние и нижние отступы?

Tags: css

Есть следующие теги со стилями:

```
.content_text h1 {
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.content_text h2 {
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

.content_text p {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.content_text ol {
    margin: 15px 0 15px 30px;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}

.content_text ul {
    margin: 15px 0 15px 30px;
    list-style-type: square;
}

.content_text img {
    display: block;
    margin: 25px 0;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Каждый из этих тегов в произвольном порядке может быть вставлен в тег `blockquote` со стилями

```
.content_text blockquote {
    margin: 25px 0 25px 13px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    border-left: 5px  solid #e9eaec;
    background: #f7f7f8;
}
```

Как правильно убрать верхний отступ у первого элемента, и нижний отступ у последнего элемента?

Делаю так, но не уверен в правильности решения:

```
.content_text blockquote h1:first-child, 
.content_text blockquote h2:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote h1:last-child, 
.content_text blockquote h2:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote ol:first-child, 
.content_text blockquote ul:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote ol:last-child, 
.content_text blockquote ul:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote img:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote img:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам в принципе не важно с какого тега будет начинаться или заканчиваться структура в blockquote то это все можно б было сократить до

```css
.content_text blockquote {
  margin: 25px 0 25px 13px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid #e9eaec;
  background: #f7f7f8;
}

.content_text blockquote>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.content_text blockquote>*:last-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_text">
  <blockquote>
    <h1>Text 1</h1>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Text 2</p>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote>
    <h2>Text 2</h2>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```